# Jsoup - get text from all elements with a particular class under a Specified class

Tags: java, jsoup

I have an HTML like,

```
<aside class="continfo">
<p>
  <span class="jtel"></span>
  <a class="tel" href="tel:+918041240281">+(91)-80-41240281</a>, 
  <a class="tel" href="tel:+918041240282">41240282</a>
</p>
</aside>
```

here there are two elements with 'tel' class, how can I extract both of these? How can i extract if the number of these classes with the name 'tel' is not known by the program? Please help.

The final Goal is to get all the text in the tel class elements.

I have tried working it out with next sibling element. but no luck there. I might have tried it wrong though. Please correct me or help me achieve what i am trying here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) you can found same samples:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a.tel");
for (Element el: links) {
   String tel = el.attr("href"); //.If you want the href attr
   // String tel = el.text() if you want the inner text
}
```